# Spring test @Transactional with @Nested junit classes

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-test, spring-transactions

I am encountering a problem in spring transactions: even though I see in the output that a transaction is created and rolled back after each test method; when I check the database content, it still keeps the document that was saved during the transaction.
I ran mongodb instance in replica mode following instructions from here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/.

My test class is defined as follows:

```
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = ["test"])
@DisplayName("Login Functionality Test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = [TestConfiguration::class])
class LoginFunctionalityTest @Autowired constructor(
    private val mockMvc: MockMvc,
    private val userRepository: UserRepository,
    private val openUserRepository: OpenUserRepository,
    private val patientRepository: PatientRepository,
    private val passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder,
    private val jwtMatcher: JWTMatcher,
    @Value("\${secret:sD1fRUWtBdfA8BNcbf}") private val fastLoginSecret: String
) {

    private val existingUsersPassword = "SOME_PASSWORD"
    private val userFastLoginTokenSecret = "ANY_SECRET"

    private lateinit var existingUser: User
    private lateinit var existingOpenUser: OpenUser
    private lateinit var existingPatient: Patient

    @BeforeEach
    fun prepareContext() {
        println("Init db")
        existingUser = userRepository.save(User(null, now(), "test", "test", "test@test.test", passwordEncoder.encode(existingUsersPassword), UserAuthority.Patient, true, true))
        existingOpenUser = openUserRepository.save(OpenUser(null, "ANY", nextExpiryDate()))
        existingPatient = patientRepository.save(Patient(null, existingUser))
    }

    @DisplayName("Login Controller")
    @Nested
    inner class LoginControllerTest{

        @Test
        fun `should return unauthorized 401 status code when user logins with not existing email`() {
            val invalidEmail = "INVALID_EMAIL"
            assertThrows<EmptyResultDataAccessException> { userRepository.findByEmail(invalidEmail) }

            mockMvc.post("/auth/login") {
                param("username", invalidEmail)
                param("password", existingUsersPassword)
            }.andExpect {
                jsonPath("$.status", equalToIgnoringCase(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.name))
                jsonPath("$.error",StringContains(true,"Invalid login credentials"))
                jsonPath("$.data", nullValue())
                status { isUnauthorized() }
            }
        }
        ...

    }

    @ActiveProfiles(profiles = ["open-user"])
    @DisplayName("Open User Login Controller")
    @Nested
    inner class OpenUserControllerLoginTest(){

        @Test
        fun `should return bad request 400 status when any of the required login parameters are missing`(){
            val validFastLoginToken = String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(passwordEncoder.encode("$userFastLoginTokenSecret${existingUser.passwordHash}$fastLoginSecret").toByteArray()))
            mockMvc
                .post("/auth/login/fast") {
                    param("userId", existingUser.id!!)
                    param("secret", userFastLoginTokenSecret)
                    param("fastLoginToken", validFastLoginToken)
                }.andExpect {
                    jsonPath("$.data.isUserActivated", equalTo(existingUser.activated))
                    jsonPath("$.data.accessToken",jwtMatcher.matches(existingUser))
                    jsonPath("$.status", equalToIgnoringCase(HttpStatus.OK.name))
                    jsonPath("$.error", nullValue())
                    status { isOk() }
                    content { contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) }
                }
        }
        ...

    }
```

The output in console has the "Init db" printed between creation and roll back of transaction.

It works correctly only if I move @ActiveProfiles from @Nested class to the outer class. Seems like @ActiveProfiles causes context reload but I don't know why this causes problems with transactions.

Comment: What version of Spring Framework are you using?